# how to get multiple inputs in same line without knowing the number of inputs in c?

Tags: c

the input I have to get is

```
11:00 12:00 10:45 10:15
```

I don't know the number of inputs
the length of the input string is between 4 to 10000

Comment: Use a loop until there is no more input? You'll need to give more detail if you want more specific help. Where does the input come from? How is the input terminated? What specific problem do you have in reading it?

Comment: `while (scanf("%d:%d", &h, &m) == 2) { ... }` ... but keep in mind that `scanf()` is not a good tool for dealing with user (or file) input.

Comment: @pmg can you explain why scanf equals to 2 ? by the way tq for your response

Comment: `2` is the number of assignments a successful `scanf()` has to do: one for `&h`, another for `&m`. The `scanf("%d:%d", &h, &m)` can return `EOF`, `0`, `1`, or `2`. Of those 4 four returns, only `2` is usable. A return of `1` would be for example, for input `"17foo"`

Comment: The other option is to read the entire line with `fgets` using a 10K buffer. Then use `strtok` in a loop to get each token, and `sscanf(token, "%d:%d", &h, &m)` to convert the token.

Comment: Note that even with the buffer solution you should still check the return value of `sscanf`, just as shown for the `scanf` solution. In any solution, once the call fails you might want to add a check if there's still invalid input left and add appropriate error handling.

Comment: thank you for your response guys I got it!